# JTextField get values based on condition

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Am using JTextField for get average.It means the average must be start with 0 to 100.so the textfield allow to access the 0 to 100 only.If I give 101 means the value don't added in the textfield.how to set the condition for this problem?

Comment: I can't really understand the question, but do you mean should I plug in 0 and 100 or 1 and 101?

Comment: Does the calculation ('average') even factor into the question?
Are you asking how to limit the input into a textfield to values that can be parsed to integers between 0 and 100?

Comment: I plug in that text field 0,1,2,3,...upto 100.when I enter 101 in that text field It wont accept 101

Comment: average is just example.I enter 0 to 100 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use KeyListener where you can do the validation.

For example

```
final JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

      }

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
// Here write the comparison logic
                 if (Integer.parseInt(myTextField.getText()) > 100){
                     myTextField.setText(""); // Make it blank
                 }
      }

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
      }
    });
```

You can use KeyAdapter as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: the IF condition can't be executed.

Comment: Thats my mistake. you put the validation in keyReleased. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @kleopatra There we are taking care so that user may not enter a wrong value.

Comment: wrong place - search this forum for some reasons. BTW, you _never_ use a keyListener for _anything_ in Swing, there are higher level abstractions for (nearly) every use-case

Comment: If you want validation on a textfield, you use the `JFormattedTextField`. If you do not want that, apply your validation on the `Document` but not with the `KeyListener`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead.

See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The visible data that is displayed in a JTextField is a java.lang.String object.

If you want to put a numeric type in it (let's say float), you have to do something like this:

```
JTextField tf=new JTextField();
float average=//get the average however you wish...

if( ( average <= 100 ) && ( average >= 0 ) )
tf.setText(String.valueOf(average));
```

this is trivial enough for me to want to ask more questions about your programming background though. Was this a question related to the JTextField, or was this about the actual condition?

Comment: only I need to enter in that text field 0 to 100.

Comment: It is not about accepting a numeric value but it is about preventing the input number